# Debian 9 TYPO3 8.7.20

Tags: installation, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have had a problem with Debian 9 and Typo3 8.7.20 for two days now and am currently desperate to log in at the Typo3 backend.
The Composer installation of Typo3 was successful up to the point mentioned above. The database tables were all created. I can also log in to the install tool and create a second admin, etc. but the backend does not work. I also repeated the Typo3 installation and always come back to the same result.

In typo3 sys_log there is the following hint:
error: 3
details: Login-attempt from% s (% s) for username '% s' with an empty password!
log_data: a: 3: {i: 0; s: 13: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; i: 1; s: 0: ""; i: 2; s: 16: "r_admin";}

Unfortunately, I can not find any info with Google

in php.ini I also adjusted the values:
max_execution_time 240
max_input_vars 1500
memory_limit 256M

If you could help me with this problem, I would be very happy. I hope there is a simple solution that I just did not find.

Comment: Maybe you can add your LocalConfiguration.php (remove any credentials)?

Comment: Many thanks!

http://hellmann-online.de/doc/LocalConfiguration.php.txt

Comment: I see a configuration for rsaauth there. Maybe EXT:rsaauth is activated. Not sure if it interferes with loginSecurityLevel=normal. I would either deactivate the extension (via PackageStates.php) or change to loginSecurityLevel=rsa

Comment: I didn't change the values. It was the default values after downloding with 
composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution /usr/local/typo3/typo3_src-8_composer/ ^8

Comment: Now I set both to normal and the EXT:rsaauth was always deactivated. I still can't log in to the backend with this changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have [BE][loginSecurityLevel] set to 'rsa' (InstallTool or LocalConfiguration.php) but extension rsaauth is missing? (If your site is on https you can safely set it to 'normal')

**Some more hints for debugging:**

You can choose 'Debug' under Configuration Presets in the InstallTool

The TYPO3 logs are in typo3temp/var/logs/typo3*.log

Do you get any JavaScript errors from the login page?

Comment: Many thanks for the help! I've found out the following strange behavior now. If I activate the logging I can log in at the backend suddenly. After I disable logging the login on the backend does not work any more. Also the login screen looks different.
[BE][loginSecurityLevel] was always set to 'normal'

Comment: Could you provide screens of the two different-looking login screens?
What doe the php/apache-log and the javascript-console say?